# Send all files on Desktop to Evernote then delete

Tags: applescript

Good morning,

I am trying to write an AppleScript that I can run that will send all the files on my desktop to Evernote, and then delete the files. My code to date is:

```
on run {input}

tell application "Finder"
    select every file of desktop
end tell

tell application "Evernote"
    repeat with SelectedFile in input
        try
            create note from file SelectedFile notebook "Auto Import"
        end try

    end repeat

end tell

tell application "Finder"
    delete every file of desktop
end tell

end run
```

If I run this then the first and last 'tell' work fine (ie. the script highlights then deletes all the files on the desktop), but the middle 'tell' doesn't do anything.

However, if I manually highlight all the files on the desktop and then run just the middle 'tell' then it imports fine - each item into a separate note as intended.

As you can tell, I am new to AppleScript - I suspect I need to put the selected files in an array of some sort, but can't figure it out. Help!

Many thanks

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code fails because there is no relation between your `input` variable and the selection of files via Finder – which means that your list is empty, and Evernote is not processing anything at all. You have obfuscated the problem by wrapping the Evernote import command in a `try` block without any error processing, which means **all** errors just go unnoticed (to avoid this kind of problem, it is good practice to always log the error message in an `on error` clause, if nothing else).

Also, you don’t actually need to select files on the Desktop via AppleScript to process them. The following code will grab all visible files (excluding pseudo-files like packages / apps):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set desktopFiles to every disk item of (desktop folder of user domain) whose visible is true and class is file
end tell
```

Pass the list you retrieved that way to Evernote for processing:

```
repeat with aFile in desktopFiles as list
    try
        tell application "Evernote" to create note from file (aFile as alias) notebook "Auto Import"
        tell application "System Events" to delete aFile
    on error errorMessage
        log errorMessage
    end try
end repeat
```

and you are good to go.

Note that by judiciously placing the deletion command (right after the import command, inside the try block, inside the loop over all files), you make sure it is only called if Evernote does not error on import while avoiding having to iterate over the files several times.

A final note: you don’t have to use the block syntax for `tell` statements if there is only one command to execute – using `tell <target> to <command>` is easier and will keep you out of nested context hell.

*Thanks @adayzone for corrections on list handling and alias coercion*

Comment: Hi kopischke.  desktopFiles is already a list, you can remove "as list" from your repeat command. Also, why ((path of aFile) as alias) and not aFile as alias?

Comment: I have found `every` filters often return single items instead of single item lists when there is only one match – coercing the returned value to a list will make sure the loop works no matter what. And *System Events* returns `disk item` objects, which cannot be coerced to `alias` objects directly – hence the detour via the path property.

Comment: tell application "System Events" to get alias of every disk item of folder "Applications" of startup disk whose visible is true

Comment: tell application "System Events" to set listTest to every file of (desktop folder of user domain) whose name is "list_test.txt"
 ... return class of listTest

Comment: @adayzdone: `alias` is not a property of `disk item` – in the *System Events* terminology it designates file system aliases. Your `alias of every disk item` statement returns a nested, blank list – not a list of AppleScript aliases of disk items, as it is intended to do. However, you are right on the money as to the `every` filter returning a list no matter what (one match, no matches, multiple matches) – seems I’m following a bit of “belt and suspenders” approach there. Edited to reflect that (also simplified the filter to use positive class matching, instead of negative).

Comment: Hi Kopischke - many thanks for your comment. When I try and run your script above I get an error, and the compiler says "Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier" and points to the Catch clause. An thoughts?

Comment: @Rich: argh, yes, stupid me – AppleScript’s catch clause is in fact called `on error`. Script amended, should run fine now.

Comment: @Kopiscke I still don't understand your logic. Any disk item I can think of that can't be coerced into an alias with an "as alias" statement would still fail in your try statement. For example, tell application "System Events" to set xxx to file "Safari.app" of
folder "Applications" as alias fails because System Events returns a file package rather than a file. However, I don't believe Evernote will import the Safari application into a note. So I can wrap my head around it, please provide an example of disk item that can't be converted with "as alias" that can be imported into Evernote.

Comment: @adayzdone: you are right, System Events `file` objects seem to map to AppleScript `file` objects and hence can be coerced to `alias` – and as the script in its current incarnation only returns `file` objects, the `path to` roundtrip is unnecessary. Not sure what this has to do with what Evernote will or will not import, however (the `try` block is meant to make sure only successfully imported files will be deleted, not as a way to let Evernote filter what will or will not be imported – esp. as Evernote **will** happily import packages, including Safari.app, compressing them to ZIP archives).

Comment: I assumed that Evernote would not import a package, so even if you excluded the "class is file", the first statement in the try block would produce an error. Thanks for the heads up about that.

Comment: \[and as an OT conclusion … before anybody asks: yes, I tested. Marvel at an [Evernote note created by importing Safari.app](http://cl.ly/GDyn)\]

Comment: @adayzdone: thanks for the heads-up on *System Events* `file` object coercion – I’ve never handled those exclusively before, only mixed bags of `disk item` objects, which you cannot consistently coerce to `alias` objects, and thus assumed this was true of anything in the `disk item` object hierarchy. The wonders of OSA scripting dictionaries never cease to amaze me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tell application "System Events" to set xxx to get every file of (desktop folder of user domain) whose visible is true

repeat with i from 1 to count of xxx
    set SelectedFile to item i of xxx as alias
    try
        tell application "Evernote" to create note from file SelectedFile notebook "Auto Import"
        tell application "Finder" to delete SelectedFile
    end try
end repeat
```

Thanks @fanaugen

Comment: @Rich: Also, you should delete only the files that are in `xxx`, rather than **every** file on the Desktop. Just add a `tell app "Finder" to delete SelectedFile` inside the `repeat` loop.